# Form different inputs enctypes

Tags: html, node.js

I'm actually sending a form in my nodejs app, which contains both a file input & multiple text inputs, but when i set the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ( which is important to upload the file) the text inputs result as `"undefined"` !

What can i do to fix this ?

Comment: Can you clarify more? Code snippet showing error would be helpful.

Comment: There are no errors, the form post request is good, and i can store it in the database, the image is uploaded but the text fields values are "undefined" , when i change enctype to it's default type , the image fails to upload but the text fields are good

Comment: Problem Solved, was a var placement error Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Node,

I think you are using basic setup with body-parser in this. The body-parser can't handle or may be deprecated for files. so use connect-multiparty module in your app for handling files.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty

Now you will get the image in req.files.